# Why does Vim run python2 while it's compiled with +python3?

Tags: python, vim

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)
Included patches: 1-1453
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +wildignore
```

I have ignored others in the list by just showing the -python and + python3.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.9
```

While in the vim I got:

```
$vim test.py    
:!python --version
    Python 2.7.17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `:!cmd` you are running cmd on the shell. This has not much to do with vim. To check which version of python vim is using internally do `:python3 import sys; print(sys.version)` inside vim.

Comment: Thanks @blues. `:python import sys; print(sys.version)` still shows python2 is the default. `2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09)
[GCC 7.4.0]  `. Some suggestions for setting Pyhon3 as default?

Comment: You need to actually specify `:python3` with the 3.

Comment: Solved by `nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>` in `.vimrc`